How to associate a Trust store to an ALB with AWS CLI
In the context of configuring mTLS above ALBs, I need to automate the configuration with AWS CLI.
I know how to check if a Trust store is associated with an ALB with the describe-trust-store-associations API. But I can't find how to create this association.
I didn't find anything in any API under elbv2.
How can I do that ?

Ok, I finally found the solution :

First extract the HTTPS listener ARN associated to the ALB (elbv2 describe-listener API call, and filter out on "Protocol")
Then update the listener to attach the Trust store (Use --mutual-authentication in elbv2 modify-listener API)

